# How does NFC p2p work on Nokia series S40

Tags: java

I am working on POC NFC for p2p communication between two Nokia emulators.
Actually I have downloaded the Nokia series S40 emulator, so it has an option for NFC. Kindly inform me if anyone has any idea whether Nokia S40 has a functionality for NFC p2p communication. If this functionality is supported in this series, please inform me how it works.

Comment: afaik there is no NFC support for S40. Even if there is, am sure you cannot test it on a emulator without actual NFC device.

Comment: Hi CodeMan, if Nfc is not supported on nokia S40, do u have any idea in which j2me nokia phone it supported NFC p2p. actually, i don't have real device to test the NFC, so iam trying to connect it only in simulator. if u have any idea please share me your opinion..
btw, thank u soo much for giving me the tips.